# Migs omnipay library documentation

Tags: virtual, omnipay

I have just started a project on integrating mastercard as a payment option for my website. I love the structuring of the Omnipay - MiGS library but I'd love to see a documentation on the usage of the library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the latest omnipay code from github there are many more examples in the class headers now.